# Laplace transform of the logarithmic integral function

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, laplace-transform

What is the Laplace transform of the logarithmic integral function $\text{li}(t)$. Meaning, how to compute the integral :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\text{li}(t)e^{-st}dt$$

Comment: Do you sure about domain of $li$, I think the domain of $li$ must be $[0,1]$, Am I wrong ?

Comment: You may interpret this as a principal value integral